# Уникальная страница на сайте asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-core-mvc, site

Необходимо создать простейший чатик в asp.net core mvс, но чтобы чат был не сразу после захода на сайт. Пользователь заходит на сайт, есть кнопочка "создать чат", нажимает на нее, его перекидывает на уникальную страницу чата с уникальным url, где он пока один. Другие пользователи смогут к нему присоединиться, если перейдут по уникальному url. Вопрос: как создать этот уникальный url и страницу?

Если вопрос слишком простой или глупый, то прошу не ругаться на меня, я новичок и только начинаю разбираться с этой темой

Comment: страница одна, но в url содержит id этого чата, скорее всего информацию о этом чате вы все равно будете сохранять где-то на бекенде, например: chat/1, chat/2, ....

Comment: На бекенде, т.е. в бд?

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно дать ответ по одной простой причине - реализация подобного зависит от того как написан сам чат, что он может, на чем, и так далее. Сейчас у вас все на уровне "хочу". Продумайте сами что в каждом чате должно быть, как это хранить, и так далее, основываясь на это быстро поймете как сделать ссылку.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду просто форум или чат с перепиской в реальном времени,   если в реальном времени,  то кроме ASP.NET,  можно будет использовать так же еще и SignalR,  но такой "простейший чатик" в реальном времени это уже не для новичков.

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak, да, чат в реальном времени. Вообще реализация такого чата с SignalR есть даже в документации, так что есть возможность изучить такой код. Но вот именно создание таких отдельных комнат- чатов мне кажется я не смогла отыскать. Я же правильно размышляю, что информацию о всех таких "чат-комнатах" нужно сохранять в бд, у каждой комнаты будет уникальный id, и уже на основе этого айди создавать уникальную ссылку для комнаты? В бд также можно сохранять информацию о том, какие пользователи присоединены к чату...

Comment: Если мои мысли не верны, я буду благодарна если подскажете! Может, какие конкретно темы изучить в интернете, чтобы лучше разобраться, буду только рада

Comment: Я видел реализацию с помощью SignalR, комнат для чатов,  где в базе данных хранилась инфа о всех комнатах, по поводу хранения информации о пользователях присоединенных к чату,  не уверен...  Вот [видео](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm8yroElV52ikUZu6IE_9bZX), с примерами реализации чатов на SignalR, надеюсь что вам это поможет,  а также надеюсь, что такую ссылку, модераторы не посчитают спамом, так как вы спрашиваете, о том где можно посмотреть примеры такой реализации...

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak, спасибо большое!